# Laravel validator required specific word

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I need to validate a string must contains a specific word in the controller.
Something Like this ("%name%" is necessary):

```
$request->validate([
   'pattern' => ['required', 'must_contains:%name%'],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Custom Rule. To create the custome rule you can do:

`php artisan make:rule StrMustContain`

Setup class like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class StrMustContain implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return str_contains('Magic Phrase', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The expected pattern does not match.';
    }
}
```

Then you can use like:

```
$request->validate([
   'pattern' => ['required', new StrMustContain],
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it was a little imperfect.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom validation using this command:

`php artisan make:rule StrMustContain`

And then changed the class like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class StrMustContain implements Rule
{
    public $str;
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($str)
    {
        $this->str = $str;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return str_contains($value, $this->str);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The phrase '.$this->str.' is required.';
    }
}
```

Then I used that:

```
$request->validate([
   'pattern' => ['required', new StrMustContain('%name%')],
]);
```